# How do you call a value in a list within a json dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm using api's to call movie reviews in the format 'title': [rating, review]. After using a json.loads() function the json list looks something like this:

```
listResult: {'Shawsank Redemption': [10, 'I love this movie so much'], 'Tropic Thunder': [9,'This was an awesome movie for sure'], 'Ted': [8, 'Hilarious throughout the entire movie']}
```

I have to return the highest rated movie, I'm assuming I have to use a for loop to find the max value but I'm unsure how to access just the rating value within the list

Comment: What you posted is not a valid python object. What is `listResult`?

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem, is there still something unclear?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your dictionary has the name `listResult` (which you should change, it's not a list), use the built in `max` function and provide a custom key-function:

```
>>> listResult = {'Shawsank Redemption': [10, 'I love this movie so much'], 'Tropic Thunder': [9,'This was an awesome movie for sure'], 'Ted': [8, 'Hilarious throughout the entire movie']}
>>> max(listResult, key=lambda movie: listResult[movie][0])
'Shawsank Redemption'
```

The keyfunction is used to define the criteria by which the movie-names are ordered. For each movie, we're getting the first element of the corresponding list.

Comment: Good answer! I have never thought of doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to access the rating part of the python list.

```
listResult = {'Movie': [10, "I love this Movie"]}

rating = listResult["Movie"][0]

print rating  // Prints 10
```

Then just compare each of the ratings to find the max one.